# Кастомный fontFamily

Tags: java, android, шрифты

Если у `TextView` в API > 16 задать

```
android:fontFamily="serif"
```

то шрифт будет другой, могу ли я куда-то поместить файл с нужным мне шрифтом, и задавать его таким образом? Или например заменить `serif` на нужный мне?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместите файл со шрифтом в папку с проектом (лучше создать папку font)

```
android:fontFamily="@font/MyOwnAmazingFont.ttf"
```